# How to make homemade ice cream with a chocolate swirl

Tags: chocolate, ice-cream

My favorite ice cream flavor has swirls of gooey chocolate running through vanilla ice cream.

What do I have to do to reproduce this effect with homemade ice cream?

I tried adding chocolate sauce near the end of churning but it was too thoroughly churned in. I have tried swirling the chocolate sauce in manually with a spoon after the churn but before freezing but the syrup mostly just floated on top.

I am using a simple syrup based chocolate sauce. 
What technique should I use to produce my chocolate swirls? Does the consistency of the syrup play a role? Would some other chocolate sauce work better- such as hot fudge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I've done this in the past, I did two things differently.

1. I used more of a fudge sauce that would thicken and get somewhat firmer when cold.  Like a fudge sauce or such.  Syrup just mixes too easy.
2. Mixing a swirl into a deeper container like the churning tub proved somewhat diffcult.  As I tried to swirl, it would mix instead.  Instead, I spread the ice cream in a large cake pan, poured the fudge over, swirled in a bit with the knife and then set it in the freezer for about 1 hour.  Then when everything was pretty firm, I scooped it up into the final container in as large of sections as possible.  It worked *great*.

Answer (score 1):

With the semi frozen still soft icecream you could try placing it in a piping bag with a large or no nozzle and add some off the ripple flavour to the bag using a knife and very slightly push it through the icecream and then squeeze out through the piping bag into a continer, im planning on using this method to make a marshmellow ripple in my flake and vanilla iceceam base. I love making and experimenting with icecream texture and flavours. yum!

For  a more liquid flavouring like chocolate sauce maybe try layering a thin amount of icecream then swirl a little amount of sauce then ice cream then swirl then ice cream etc..

Comment: Sounds interesting! Let me know how the piping bag experiment goes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about trying this method so it's not tried and true. However, I have an injector that I use for putting Cajun spices into a fried turkey. I'm thinking about loading up the injector with something like a hot fudge sauce and randomly putting swirls into the semi-soft ice cream, right after it has finished churning. The idea is similar to the pastry bag method mentioned previously. The downside would be needing to refill the injector a few times but is shouldn't be too hard using a small gauge funnel.

Comment: I'm interested to hear how this works out!

Answer (score -1):

This is probably very hard to reproduce

Commercial ice-cream is nearly fully frozen, but still in a semi-liquid form, and then put through an augured dispenser into the packaging tubs. The auger can exert great pressure

At this point injectors add colouring and flavouring for swirls which flows with the ice cream into the tub (similar technique to striped toothpaste)

You could try using an auger based juicer (without filter screen) or auger based meat grinder?